# Can't Connect to Perforce from PowerBuilder after server Changed to Unicode

Tags: powerbuilder

I use a third party perforce service so I don't have any control over the server environment/config.  I've been working it with PB 12.5 for a little over a year with no problems.  Recently, when I started up PB I got an error that it couldn't initialize Perforce.

After that error, I tried the Perforce command line tool (p4), and when I logged in with that, I got an error suggesting that my character set was not compatible with the server's unicode character set.  I then added P4CHARSET=utf8 to my p4config.txt and that fixed the command line and other Perforce tools, but I still can't connect with PowerBuilder 12.5.

Is there any way for me to get PB12.5 to connect again?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Perforce but I did a search and found something that might help.
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/sccpluginnotes.txt

New functionality in 2005.1

```
    Support for Unicode Servers
        It is now possible to use P4SCC.DLL with unicode enabled servers.
        See Tech. Note 66 for more information about supported character
        sets.
```

So I guess you need to make sure the SCC API Plugin you are using supports the Unicode server.

Comment: Thanks Roland.  I am using the latest version of the SCC API plugin (2012.1 I believe).  I also uninstalled and re-installed, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three situations that could be affected. I'm thinking that if they switched to Unicode and PB is using an ASCII version of the DLL, or specifies ASCII than it could cause problems.

**External Functions**

There might be local or global external functions defined that specifically state ANSII or Unicode. An example might be like this and need to be recompiled.

```
Function ulong GetDriveTypeW (string drive) library "KERNEL32.DLL:ASCII"
```

**Edit Mask Style**

If you use the “#” or “a” special characters in a mask, Unicode characters, spaces, and other characters that are not alphanumeric do not display.

**PowerBuilder 10 and higher**

Source code is in Unicode UTF-16LE (Little Endian)